# How to integrate the following, and what do the results signify?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac{1}{(a^2-x^2)^n}dx$$

Our teacher told us to simply memorize the following answer to this, $a\sin{\theta}$ or $a\cos{\theta}$.

But how is it actually derived, and as I missed that class, what does the $\theta$ mean in this case?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the integral of a rational function, all rational functions can be integrated by partial fractions. Take the case $n=1$ then

$$\frac{1}{a^2-x^2}=\frac{1}{(a-x)(a+x)}=\frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{1}{a-x}+\frac{1}{a+x}\right)$$

So the integral is $$\frac{1}{2a}\ln \left(\frac{a+x}{a-x}\right)$$
In general,

$$\frac{1}{(a-x)^n(a+x)^n}=\frac{A_1}{a-x}+\cdots +\frac{A_n}{(a-x)^n}+
\frac{B_1}{a+x}+\cdots +\frac{B_n}{(a+x)^n}$$
you will then have to solve for coefficients $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 3):

He probably meant "use the sub $x = a \sin{\theta}$". Can you see how to continue?

Comment: Yes thank you! :D
I couldn't interpret the results :P
However, is there any simple reasoning for the substitution or does it have a complex proof? I understand how the values cancel out perfectly, but is there a purely algebraic view to it as well? :/ I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: I don't quite understand. The goal is to reduce it to a trig integral. Then look it up in the table. Integrals of many algebraic fractions are (inverse) trig functions, e.g. $\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \arctan x$

Comment: @PA6OTA the goal is not to reduce it to a trig integral in order to look it up in a table.  The goal should be to reduce the integral to one that can be computed via other more familiar or elementary means (trig identities, partial fractions, etc.).  Over-dependence on tables is not beneficial to understanding of the subject (especially considering the average table of integrals, which is incomplete, is 1000+ pages, and can have errata of 100+pages not caught in editing).